# What is the purpose of the additional outer async block

Tags: rust, async-await

In a lot of SO questions and also in a lot of external, reputable resources, such as the [tokio tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/spawning) I've seen people use an additional `async` block such as:

```rust
tokio::spawn(async move {
    process(socket).await;
});
```

instead of doing just

```
tokio::spawn(process(socket));
```

Both resolve to some `Future` and `spawn()` expects

```
pub fn spawn<T>(future: T) ....
where T: Future + ....
```

so I cannot understand the need for the additional `async {}` block.

Is it really necessary ? And is there any difference besides being a "visual marking" that this is an async code?

Comment: This might be unanswerable because it boils down to asking those people why they did it. I'd wager that people use `async move {}` because it works in general (e.g., if you do more than one thing or if the single thing you do isn't even async), while "inlining" it is a special case of exactly one awaitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are slightly different, depending on the implementation of `process`.

If `process` is defined like this:

```
fn process(socket: Socket) -> impl Future {
    // non-async stuff
    println!("non-async stuff");

    // async stuff
    async {
        println!("async stuff");
    }
}
```

Then invoking it with `tokio::spawn(process(socket));` will execute the first line immediately and only the remaining sub-task, which prints `"async stuff"`, will be scheduled.

If it defined like this:

```
async fn process(socket: Socket) {
    // non-async stuff
    println!("non-async stuff");

    // async stuff
    async {
        println!("async stuff");
    }.await;
}
```

Then `tokio::spawn(process(socket));` will initally do nothing and will print both `"non-async stuff"` and `"async stuff"` when the scheduled task is executed.

Wrapping the call in a extra `async` block will make the two versions behave the same way. Whether or not this is the reason for the extra `async` block or if it is "needed" in the examples that you've seen is a question for the authors of those examples.